# Use an if else function to resize content using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm new to the website so I apologize if I'm doing something wrong here.

Alright so here is my problem. I have 3 div next to each others. One of them is a menu, the second is a player and the third a chat box.

The set up is the following. When I open the menu to display the submenu, the player slides out to the right pushing the chat box under the player.

I thought of using javascript to resize the chat box size whenever the menu is triggered.

This is what I have so far :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".zocial-youtube").click(function(){
    $(".container").css({"width": "30%"});
});
```

});

And it works!

The problem is when I close the sub menu and the player slides back to its original position, the chat box does not resize to its original size.

I feel like I need to use the if else function but I can't figure out the code.

Could you help me with the function please?

THIS IS THE WHOLE CODE : https://codepen.io/LAMUUZ/pen/JJrodY

Comment: `if..else` is not a function, it's a statement ... If you'd show the code where the actual problem occurs, you might get some answers.

Comment: What's its original size? i.e the `.container` has a specific width css property before resizing? Additionally, does it the only class of that name? Please try to show us the part of your HTML that holds those elements.

Comment: how is the submenu being closed? the html would be useful

Comment: This is the whole code :

https://codepen.io/LAMUUZ/pen/JJrodY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
You can create a class having width 30%

```
.tempWidth {
width: 30% !important
}
```

Then use toggleClass on container and pass in the class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".zocial-youtube").click(function(){
      $(".container").toggleClass("tempWidth");
  });
});
```

Did you try using toggle instead of click ?

Comment: it seems toggle has been deprecated.

Comment: what if he doesnt click on the same button to open/close the menu? html is needed for a complete solution

Comment: Envision answer does fit the situation. create a class like he said and on the click event use toggleClass('tempWidth')

Comment: Alright it works! Thanks a lot. I'm a self taught when it comes to code so sometime it gets really hard. 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you could use an if else statement and it might not be a bad exercise for you to use. in that case you should set a variable like on the intial click and then change that variable around...

Something like this

```
 var makeDivSmall = true;
 $(".zocial-youtube").click(function(){
     if(makeDivSmall){
     $(".container").css({"width": "30%"});
     makeDivSmall = false;
     }
     else{
     $(".container").css({"width": "100%"});
     makeDivSmall = true;
     }
 });
```

You can also accomplish it with only one if statement like this:

```
  $(document).ready( function(){
     $('.zocial-youtube').click( function() {
     var toggleWidth = "100%"
     if($(".container").css("width") == "100%"){
           toggleWidth = "30%" 
      }

    $('.container').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
     });
 });
```

Also jquery has a method called toggle which can be convenient for things like this. The basic implementation just toggles an element visible state.

By the way you speak about sliding so maybe you want to put a slide effect when the width changes rather just snapping it to 30% ? have a look here

```
 $( "container" ).animate({
     width: "30%"
   }, 1500 );
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. You can give me the green tick.